# MultiUploader render issue (GWT + mvp4g)

Tags: java, gwt, visibility, mvp4g

I am using MultiUploader and sometimes "uploader" button is cropped. It happens only if at the time of page loading uploader button is invisible. When I further make it visible, button becomes visible, but cropped. If page is loading with param=true everything is okay.

```
//mvp4g is used
public void onEventBusEventName(boolean param) {
 ...
 view.uploader.setVisible(param);
 ...
 this.view.logoUploader.setI18Constants(UiConstants.INSTANCE);
 this.view.logoUploader.setStyleName("logo-uploader");
 view.logoUploader.addOnFinishUploadHandler(new IUploader.OnFinishUploaderHandler() {
  @Override
  public void onFinish(IUploader uploader) {
   if (uploader.getStatus() == IUploadStatus.Status.SUCCESS) {
    String fileId = uploader.getFileInput().getName();
    updateLogo(fileId);
   } else {
    Window.alert(uploader.getStatus().toString());
   }
  }
 });
 ...
 eventBus.setCenterContent(view); //setting root widget to specified view currently showing
}
```

How it looks:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sAwL.png

ClassView:

```
@UiField
MultiUploader logoUploader;
```

ClassViewUi:

```
<gwtupload:MultiUploader type="BUTTON" ui:field="logoUploader" title="Upload new logo"
                                     avoidRepeatFiles="true" maximumFiles="1"
                                     validExtensions="jpg,png,jpeg,bmp"/>
```

Css:

```
.logo-uploader {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 float: left;
}

.logo-uploader .gwt-Button {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 171px;
 height: 26px;
 background: url(../i/sprite.png) -1px -335px no-repeat;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 line-height: 1;
 border: none;
 color: #195c84;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.logo-uploader .gwt-Button:hover {
 background: url(../i/sprite.png) -1px -362px no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: could you post the code about how you create the instance of multiuploader, the button used, and css rules

Comment: Is it possible to call forceLayout after the button gets visible?